# Next child LI that is wrapped in a different UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">One</li>
    <li class="item">Two</li>
    <li class="item">Three
        <ul>
            <li class="item">Something Original</li>
            <li class="item selected">Something</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Four 
        <ul>
            <li class="item">I want this selected next</li>
            <li class="item">Good</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, how do I find the next `li` with the `class="item"` since it is wrapped in a different container. Obviously I cannot do `$(".selected").next(".item")` so how else can I do it?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3f6v7zz/

Comment: Depends on where you're selecting from. Can you give a little more info on what you have tried?

Comment: what wrong with `.find()`

Comment: When pressing the down arrow, I need to go to the next "item". I'm not sure how to do it if it is not on the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the li elements are nested and you know that you want the next appearing li with a particular class, you can use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index) and do something like this

```
var $li = $('.item'); // <--- get the list of all lis with class .item
var index = $li.index($('.selected')); // <--- find the index of the one with .selected amongst all the lis
console.log($li.eq(index+1).html()); // <--- index+1 because you need the next appearing li after selected
```

---

If you want to move the selected class on keydown something like this should do

```
var $li = $('.item');
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    var index = $li.index($('.selected'));
    $li.eq(index).removeClass('selected');
    index = (index+1) % $li.length; // <--- to rotate the values from 0 to count of li.item elements
    $li.eq(index).addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```js
var $li = $('.item');

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    var index = $li.index($('.selected'));
    $li.eq(index).removeClass('selected');
    index = (index+1) % $li.length;
    $li.eq(index).addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">One</li>
  <li class="item">Two</li>
  <li>Three
    <ul>
      <li class="item">Something</li>
      <li class="item selected">Something Else</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Four
    <ul>
      <li class="item">I want this selected next</li>
      <li class="item">Good</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: @FirstLegion: Based on your comments below the question about down arrow I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, what does the % do on this line "index = (index+1) % $li.length;"

Comment: its a modulo operator and it sees that the value stays in between 0 and li.length. Like this 0, 1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2..... . It cycles

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for but you can use `$(Element").parent().parent().find("li");`

So in other words `.parent()` may be what you are looking for there is also `.sibling()` to find or you may want `$('li').closest('ul').find('li')`
which will go up the tree to find the nearest ul to the one you are looking for 
https://api.jquery.com/closest/

You may also use:

Vanilla JS to do something similar to what was discussed by others with $index if it makes more sense to you:
Again this isn't as efficient but that is basically what JQuery is doing:

```
var myLis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var wantedIndex;
for(var i = 0;i<myLis.length; i++){
   if(myLis[i].className === "active"){
      wantedIndex = i+1; //gets the li which is next when selecting all lis
       }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid using closest and parent as there could be multiple levels.

Comment: Also, sometimes the next one is in the same `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the selected element within all `li`s, and then increment that index to get the next one.

```js
$("ul").on("click", "li.item.selected", function() {
  var all_li = $("li.item");
  var selected_index = all_li.index(this);
  var next_li = all_li.eq((selected_index + 1) % all_li.length);
  $(this).removeClass("selected");
  next_li.addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.item.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">One</li>
  <li class="item">Two</li>
  <li class="item">Three
    <ul>
      <li class="item selected">Something</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Four
    <ul>
      <li class="item">I want this selected next</li>
      <li class="item">Good</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I used the modulus so it will wrap around at the end.